# How to give a partial access to an external developer?

Tags: php, css, laravel, collaboration, developer-tools

With our little developer team, we are currently working on a web project quite sensitive. We use Git as version control system. 
Also, we're using the MVC pattern, so our files are separated into 3 parts (views, models, controllers). We are using the laravel framework so our views is a combination of PHP, HTML, Javascript and CSS code. 
For some views, the Javascript and CSS code are directly into the view.

Now, the project is growing and we need someone to help us to do some beautiful pages with CSS. But his objective it's only to deal with CSS and nothing else.

Regarding tools that we are using, is there a way (or some best practices to apply) to give him an access to do correctly his job without give him all of our sources?

I'm thinking of tools, code refactoring, or anything else that can help us to keep our business logic away of external people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only give him access to part of the project, but still have his updates automatically reflected on your build, you could go for a solution using get submodules.

If he will really be dealing with CSS only, then make the `public` folder as a separate repository, and have it included in yours as a submodule. If he needs to have access to the HTML as well, which is very likely, make another for the `views` folder. While he still gets access to the view logic, that's probably not a big problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to do this by creating a new repository with only the public dir and the views dir.

Answer (score 1):

Use git and make a new repository for static pages and give the external people access of only static pages repository

Comment: git or any versioning system will do the job (svn...)